# Need an IDE for Android NDK + SDK development

Tags: android, debugging, sdk, ide, android-ndk

Since I've got issues with ndk development on eclipse (multiple errors when I open a .c file in the JNI so I cannot set any breakpoint without close and reopen the project after it) I was wondering if any of you has the knowledge of another IDE which would be more effective for an environment where I intent to use the NDK for calling a native library and the SDK for the rest (App gui, calls to lib, etc...)

Many thanks for your advices.

Comment: Isn't Eclipse doing this job?

Comment: Yes it does but wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend to use Android-Studio based on IntelliJ IDEA from jetBrains when there will be a v1 release, its UI is clear and effective and the debugger is less annoying than eclipse's one, however native development is a bit tricky unlike eclipse which provides the appropriated plugins when you write your module in C++ (if you do it in C, the compiler will take it as an error when you'll open your file in the IDE).
So I'll develop in native using eclipse until a native module exists for Android Studio.

Comment: also buy an 16+ GM ram PC for android studio. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eclipse, NDK can be integrated there, there are some plug-ins that you can use to debug native code.

Comment: Actually I set up the NDK environment on eclipse and also installed the CDT plugin for my native library, the app compiles well but when I want to put a breakpoint in a c file when I debug, it always shows multiple errors.

Comment: I haven't debugged native code yet, but aren't there some steps to take before debugging? Does your code compiles? If yes, follow some tutorials. If not, correct your code.

Comment: The code compiles using ndk-build, I took all the needed steps to set up the debugger but anyway many tutorials tell you how to setup your native project and the debug environment but none is talking about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about keep using Eclipse on Linux with full features. Features for Java support and Native language support.

Comment: Hi, that's what I'm already doing.
I think I'll debug the c part with ndk-gdb in command line with ddd enabled, that's the only way

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out **Visual studio 2017+** ?

Remember, with Visual studio and C/C++, you can support windows, android, (may be IOs as well but not tried) from single code.
VS is light weight but powerful IDE.

I recommend VS2017.

at [visualstudio.microsoft.com](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus-mdd/):

> Write once target all
> C++ is a great language for mobile app development
>
> Migrate existing C++ libraries to target Android, iOS, and Windows platforms or use these C++ libraries to build complete Xamarin Android Native, Java Native Interface, >or iOS applications. You can also develop complete Android Native-Activity applications all within Visual Studio.

[image]

Article: [Build an app for Android, iOS, and Windows (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/cross-platform-mobile-development-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#build-an-app-for-android-ios-and-windows-c)

Article: [Mobile Development with C++ | Windows UWP, Android and iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cross-platform/?view=msvc-160)

Video: [Getting started with ndk and visual studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SJmf1HsVQU)